# Font Awesome is not working properly - how to fix that?

Tags: android, font-awesome

I wanted to create a test app that only displays a few font awesome icons. 
I downloaded the files from [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css) and added them to my assets folder. Then I created a helper class (IconTextView) as below that include the method:

```
public static Typeface getTypeface(Context context, String font) {
        return Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font);
    }
```

then in my main activity:

```
Typeface icon = IconTextView.getTypeface(this,"fa_brands_400.ttf" );
        IconTextView iconTextView = (IconTextView) findViewById(R.id.iconTextView);
        iconTextView.setTypeface(icon);
```

on my xml I have:

```
android:id="@+id/iconTextView"
        android:layout_width="195dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="&#xf372;"
```

I get the values from [this cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet)

but instead of the actual icon, I only see the text displayed. I've tried different answers that are posted already, but the references are for older faw versions and don't apply to the new codes. I tried passing a string reference on my xml as well but it didn't work. I tried downloading the files for web and then the ones for desktop use, but it didn;t make any difference. Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: [font in xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

Comment: @Jay do I still just add the icon reference as standard android:text?

Comment: You don't have to worry about `icon` reference anymore, the `android:fontFamily="@font/fa_brands_400"` will take care of font setting. You need to create `font` resource directory inside **res**, and put your .ttf file into it.

Comment: @Jay that's what I did, my problem is how to display a specific icon from that font awesome set in my view?

Comment: Apologies. I did not understand the cheatsheet part, now I do after visiting the official site.

Comment: @Jay no worries, thanks for trying to be helpful anyway!

Comment: In [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-fontawesome-in-an-android-app--cms-24167) website, the writer wrote strings like this: &#xf1fe;  Maybe you can try changing your texts with them.

Comment: @esdoodle That's how I had them initially. When I posted the question I had changed it as I was testing out different things. Turns out the problem was with the way my android studio extracted the resource file as per the answer below. Thanks for your input though. I have now edited back my original xml in the question to reflect the solution

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. :)

Comment: Maybe try `\uf372` instead of `&#xf372;`

Comment: @KlingKlang that works as well! Thank you! Do you happen to know whether one should be preferred over the other?

Comment: No. I just happened to use that (it's Unicode style). It worked for me, therefore, I encourage using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an android studio mistake. I was setting the icon reference from the cheatsheet surrounded by &#x...; as suggested in other sources. Android studio was extracting my string resource as `<![CDATA[&#x...;]]>` in the strings.xml file. When I manually changed it to the former, it worked just fine!